# Autoboxing doesn't work with Parameterized types

Tags: java, generics, casting, autoboxing

I have a parameterized generic class X which takes a type T. On which no conditions (like T extends/implements) have been defined.

```
class X <T> {
    Map<T, String> map = new HashMap<T, String>();

    public void put() {
        map.put((T)getLong(), "");
    }

    public long getLong() {
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

We know that T is definitely an object type and not a primitive. So I'd expect the returned "long" value to be Autoboxed to Long and then the cast to T would follow, but that doesn't happen.

Compiler says "Cannot cast from long to T". If I replace the parameterized type T with "Long", there's no problem.
Can anyone explain why Java doesn't support autoboxing of primitive types when a parameterized type is involved ? Is there something I am missing ?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming all above it will work only with Long as T. You will get 'ClassCastException' for any other parametrization. So what are you trying to accomplish using Generics there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, yes, Here we can assume that T and Long are compatible types. Not really worried about the runtime ClassCastException, but the Compilation error that creeps in.

Comment: If you added `<T super Long>` it might work.

Comment: For this case 'T and Long are compatible types' means T is Long as you are not using wildcards. Long is final so using <T extends Long> is meaningless as well using <T super Long>. This question is good from the point of understanding internals but I wish you never find the code like that in your projects :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , first you should autobox then cast to T. It should be written as follows.

```
public Long getLong() {  //not long, because it's primitive
        return 0L;
    }
```

So autoboxing happens when this method returns. What happens in your case is, it doesn't autobox long primitive and you trying to cast this long primitive to T. that you simply can't do.

Comment: Yes, this works like a charm. Thanks! Wondering, why Java imposes such a restriction.

Comment: @kryptic..it's not restriction man..just you are expecting too much from java.